# Will I get an answer to this question?

Tags: logic

A [tautology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_%28logic%29), is a universal truth in formal logic. I found something similar in the following question:

> Will I get an answer to this question?

Any answer, yes or no, will answer this question, since even no, is an answer. 
I think this is related to the self-reference and to me seems to be related to the concept of tautology.

Is this further related to this quite famous example:

> If I ask you for sex, will your answer be the same as to this question?

If not where is the difference?

Comment: "I think the problem is related to the self-reference." What problem?

Comment: @ChristopherE is it clearer now?

Comment: What about "no answer"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Self reference is not related to tautologies; a tautology is a valid statement in propositional logic, that is it is true in every interpretation. Valid statements are important because they preserve truth, so we can use them to prove new things.

The sentence you have stated does not really have an interpretation in logic as it is a question, not a statement. But you might consider a statement such as "This sentence is false", which is found to be both true and false and therefore paradoxical. But it is most definitely not valid, or a tautology.

Self-reference is a very deep and interesting subject and is the foundation of [Gödel's incompleteness theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_sentence). If you are interested in self-reference and logic I would highly recommend reading [Gödel, Escher, Bach: An Eternal Golden Braid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del,_Escher,_Bach) which discusses self-reference in detail.

Comment: +1 for your answer and especially the reference, that is (still pending) on my list of books-I-will-read...